# Syncfusion grid exports empty grouped rows in excel after grouping and sorting

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion, gridgroupingcontrol

If i am exporting syncfusion in excel after doing grouping and then sorting then it will exports all the grouped rows even if they don't have any data after filter.

Please suggest me which peoperty or method i eed to call before export to excel.

This is my exporting code

```
GridExcelExport excelExport = new GridExcelExport(gridControl, fileName, ConverterOptionsExt.All);            
            excelExport.ExportNestedTable = false;


            excelExport.ExportBorderSytles = false;
            excelExport.IsApplySytles = false;

            excelExport.Export();
```

Image is also updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We were able to reproduce the issue “**Excel export exports all the grouped rows even if they don’t have any data after filter**” and have logged defect report regarding this. The fix for this issue will be included in our upcoming volume release, which is scheduled in at the end of March 2015. In order for you to get a solution for this behaviour, please contact us at Syncfusion Support or you may also open a support ticket by login in to direct trac account and mention this forum link for reference.

Please let us know if you have any concerns.